# Wordpress Shopping Cart

Tags: wordpress

I need a simple shopping cart that will display all its products(only 9) in one page with input boxes for quantity. Most shopping cart only have option to add one product at a time but  I want to add all at once.

Suppose I want to add two of seven different products to the shopping cart. Instead of adding manually again and again I want to do it at once by inputting quantity on quantity input box.

Instead of add to cart button beside each product, I want only one add to cart button with quantity input box beside each product!

Comment: This is not a suitable question for Stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.  This is just a list of job requirements, SO is a programmer's Q&A site, not a site where you can come to get all your work done for you free.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I am looking for a plugin I cannot find

Comment: Ah, ok.  Well it's still not a suitable question (it is known here as a Shopping Question, no pun intended) as it's not progamming related. It might be more on topic on wordpress.stackexchange.com bu I'm not 100%. If you need to customise the code then use SO for code questions :)

Comment: Thank You, how will I delete this question then?

Comment: As the only answer has no upvotes you should be able to delete it from the link under the question.  Looks like you have a vote though - it's up to you whether you delete it but can I say good on you for being interested in learning about SO and doing the right thing.  Welcome to the community :)

Answer (score 0):

Try SimpelCart (http://simplecartjs.org/).

It is awesome!

Comment: No thats not what I want sorry. I want a wordpress plugin first of all and then it must meet those criterias mentions

Comment: Yes it's a wordpress plugin : http://chris-wallace.com/2009/07/17/simplecartjs-a-free-wp-e-commerce-thematic-c hild-theme/   and yes, it satisfies your requirement, will need little customization.